# how to call httpconeection setRequestProperty android in loop to setHeader?

Tags: java, android, connection, httpconnection, http-request-parameters

**HTTPConnection conn** method

**setRequestProperty**

**conn.setRequestProperty("","");**

I have  different header for different URL. So, it's not fix in my project.
 I need to use a array to fill the setRequestproperty data.

Individual call for setRequestProperty it's working **1stPart** .

I tried to call same into Array it's not work "**part 2**".

```
1) conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","12345678");
  conn.setRequestProperty("ReToken", "erjeorjeorjeoureorjr");


2)  

String[] array1 = new String[]{"Authorization","12345678","RefreshToken","erjeorjeorjeoureorjr"};`

                if (array1 != null) {
                    int size = array1.length;

                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2) {
                        conn.setRequestProperty('"' + array1[i] + '"',
                                '"' + array1[i + 1] + '"');
                         Log.d(TAG,"Value Print:: " + array1[i] + " ," + 
                                 array1[i+1] );
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert something that is already a string into a string. Just remove the double quotes around the array.
Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2) {
    conn.setRequestProperty(array1[i] ,array1[i + 1]);
    Log.d(TAG,"Value Print:: " + array1[i] + " ," + array1[i+1] );
}
```